# How to pass new props to state of acomponent in Reagent?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I have a component:

```
(defn inner-input [cljs_element activeEl title]
  (let [form (atom title)]
    (fn [cljs_element activeEl title]
      [:input {:type "text"
           :onChange #(reset! form (.. % -target -value))
           :on-blur #(change-title cljs_element (.. % -target -value))
           :style {:display (if (:active (:node cljs_element)) "block" "none")
                   :width (* (+ 1 (count @form)) 8)
                   :max-width 730
                   :min-width 170}
           :value @form}])))
```

It is nested in other component:

```
(defn card-input [cljs_element activeEl]
  (fn [cljs_element activeEl]
    (let [title (:title (:node cljs_element))]
      [:div
        [inner-input cljs_element activeEl title]])))
```

When i type data to the input in the *inner-input* component, i need update the local state *form*. And when the outer component *card-input* updates i want to reset my form to new *title* prop from argument. How can i achieve that?

I tried put `(reset! form title)` between let and fn in the *inner-input* component but it will not help

Comment: as far as i remember you need to update the `form` atom in a render function, it would be called after each render call from outer component. You just need to add `(reset! form title)` right after `(fn [cljs_element activeEl title] ...`

Comment: @leetwinski but in this case `(reset! form title)` will rewrite my localstate changing in :onChange. I need change the form atom to the title from arguments only when the outer component was updated

Comment: well, your render function (reset) would only be called in case of outer component's update. After that the data would be controlled by your on-change handler

Comment: If you go the `(reset! form title`) way (within inner fn), you also have to put the let outside the outer fn, and turn it into a ratom. E.g., 

`(let [title (atom (:title (:node cljs_element)))] (fn [cljs_element activeEl] ...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reagent/track!` to listen to changes to title, and `reagent/dispose` to stop listening. You can alternatively use add-watch and remove-watch, but track is a more convenient syntax.

```
(defn inner-input [title]
  (reagent/with-let
    [form (reagent/atom @title)
     watch (reagent/track! (fn [] (reset! form @title)))]
    [:label
     "Inner input"
     [:input {:on-change (fn [e]
                           (reset! form (.. e -target -value)))
              :on-blur (fn [e]
                         (reset! title (.. e -target -value)))
              :value @form}]]
    (finally
      (reagent/dispose! watch))))

(defn card-input []
  (reagent/with-let
    [title (reagent/atom "hello")]
    [:div
     [:label "Title"
      [:input {:on-change (fn [e]
                            (reset! title (.. e -target -value)))
               :value @title}]]
     [inner-input title]]))
```

Now if you type in the inner input it will only update the outer when you exit the input box, but changing the outer title will immediately change the inner one. Is that what you wanted?

But if you don't want to pass title as a `ratom` and have to pass it as a value, then instead you can compare it to the previous value to determine if it changed, and reset form only when it changes.

```
(when (not= @previous-title title)
  (do (reset! previous-title title)
      (reset! form title)))
```

This code can go in render seeing as it is safe to call when `form` changes... nothing will happen.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i want. Before i read your answer i done it with help of the `reagent/create-class` macros. I wrote a code similar to the second variant in your answer within `:component-did-update` key, a callback function under that key have previous props within arguments